# Smooth model movement in OpenGL 3D

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, jogl

When I translate my 3D model across the screen the movement does not look smooth.  It jumps (no surprise as I am translating by a factor of 1) to each of the translated locations.  My question is how can I get the model to move across the screen without showing this jerky/jumping animation effect.
I have tried reducing the translation factor but that of course slows down the movement too much.
The following code block is in the display(GLAutoDrawable drawable){} routine:

```
for (float x = -8;x < 8; x+=2){
    for (float z = -8; z < 8; z+=2){

        view2 = rotate(view,(float)20,(float)1,(float)0,0); //rotate 30deg on x

        //rotate the model. spin on Y. (rotate is a custom func - not using 
        //old glRotate)
        view2 = rotate(view2,(float)rotAngle,(float)0,(float)1,0); 

        //transX and transY are incremented/decremented by 1 every time
        //the KeyPressed event is fired.  Animator running at 60fps.
        //translate() is a simple matrix multiplier.  This is where
        //the model gets its new co-ordinates (that it jumps to...)
        view2 = translate(view2, (float)transX - x, 0, transZ - z);

        //pass transform to the vertex shader
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(iView, 1, false, view2, 0);

        //the projection matrix (static)
        gl.glUniformMatrix4fv(iProj, 1, false, projection, 0);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL3.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36); //draw 12 triangles (36 vertices).

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redraw as fast as possible; you must achieve at least ~40 frames per second so that things appear to move smoothly; at slower frame rates you'd need motion blur to cover up the jerkiness.

Between drawing frames measure the time in between *the same points in the drawing code* of a given frame and move according to that. Note that

SwapBuffers returns almost immediately, regardless of V-Sync being enabled or not. It's the OpenGL pipeline that's going to stall eventually.

Comment: But my animator is set to 60 fps.  Is that not fast enough?

Comment: 60fps surely is fast enough. But the way you formulated your comment makes me presume, that you use some kind of timer to trigger redraw events. Don't use timers to control frames! As soon as a frame has been rendered, trigger the event that makes the next frame draw. Let V-Sync do the framerate limiting for you.

Comment: You should rather measure the elapsed time between two frames (and enable v-sync if you'd like to display 60 frames per second) to compute the translation.

Comment: @gouessej: That's what I actually meant :)